# Como hacer url amigable con .htaccess

Tags: html5, .htaccess, url

Buen día... he estado investigando acerca de este tema pero no logro hallar algo que me ayude, y es que quiero evitar que las extenciones de mi archivo se muestre en la URL (ej. contacto.php) 
¿Que debería llevar mi archivo htaccess para que se muestre contacto/?

Este es el codigo que tengo:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ contacto.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta con que tu `htaccess`, contenga lo siguiente y que lo guardes en la carpeta raíz de tu proyecto para que funcione

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

> Lo único que hemos hecho es declararle que después del punto busque
>   cualquier archivo con extensión .php y haga opcional su uso; es decir
>   que cargue el archivo sin importar si colocas el nombre completo con
>   todo y url o solo el nombre del archivo.

Es decir, debe funcionar bajo los siguiente escenarios

```
hola.php //funcionará

hola //debe funcionar
```